# Simple tensorflow keras model with single matrix multiply not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to setup a simple tf.keras model in which a vector is fed in as input and the output is the result of a single matrix multiply.

The lines of code to create the model suceed but calling it for a forward pass results in an error.

```
n_input_nodes = 2
n_output_nodes = 1

x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(n_input_nodes,))
W = tf.ones((n_input_nodes,n_output_nodes), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.matmul(x, W)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)

x_input = tf.constant([10,30.], shape=[1, 2])
output = model(x_input)
```

The final line (i.e. the forward pass) throws the following error:
`ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: [array([[1.], [1.]], dtype=float32)] - got shape [1, 2, 1], but wanted [1].`

The input is of shape (2,1) and the weight matrix has shape (2,1). Matrix multiply between the two should be a valid multiplication and result in a [1,1] tensor; however, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

They require a dense tensor and not a sparse tensor. Consider this shape

```
W = tf.ones((n_input_nodes,), dtype=tf.float32)
```

It requires a tensor of shape ( 2, ) which is dense.